# How to watch for NullPointerEx in Eclipse using Debbuger Add Watch Expression feature?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Hi how can I use that **Add Watch Expression** of eclipse to watch for any `NullPointerException`s that my application can throw ?

I saw a Guy once adding some code into that feature and with that he made eclipse debugger to stop when any NullpointerEx was "born".

I would like to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use 'watch expression'.  Go to the "breakpoints" view and add an exception breakpoint for `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this using Add Watch Expression, but [you can set breakpoints on certain types of exceptions being thrown.](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2007/04/06/eclipse-tip--breakpoint-on-exception.html)  Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I know how to do that, but I once saw a guy getting the the debug to stop on the exact moment the NullPointer happened... so the program was still running and it stopped at the exact error point. using this ** Add Watch Expression ** feature, but I cannot make it work, he did put some java code inside it, but I cannot remember what it was.

Comment: @cfontes- Hmmm, I didn't know you could do that... now I'm curious. :-)  Perhaps you should update your question to make it clearer that this is what you're asking?